# Time command not behaving correctly

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, zsh

I am having a weird problem with the time command. When I try and run

```
$ time rspec spec
```

It should return

```
Finished in 15.78 seconds
75 examples

real    0m22.334s
user    0m17.952s
sys     0m2.643s
```

But it doesn't return anything, if I run the same command via /usr/bin/time it returns

```
    5.71 real         4.51 user         0.89 sys
```

I have no idea why. I am running zsh

Comment: Your desired output format looks exactly like `bash`'s.

Comment: @DanielBeck yes! you are correct any idea on how to replicate that in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing [TIMEFMT](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_15.html):

```
$ zsh
$ TIMEFMT=$'\nreal\t%E\nuser\t%U\nsys\t%S'; time sleep 1

real    1.01s
user    0.00s
sys     0.00s
```

Comment: thanks! This worked although I have to wrap commands in ()